# List Comprehension Method Optimisation

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have developed some Python code which revolves around two custom classes - a 'Library' class (Lib) which contains a Python list of several objects based on a 'Cas' class. I've not posted the code for either of these classes here, but all you really need to know to understand my question is that the 'Library' object contains a Python list and the 'Cas' objects contain various attributes, some of which are strings and some are values.

One of the objectives of the code is to manipulate the Python list in the Library class and return a sub-set of the 'Cas' objects based on some user driven criteria. For example, return Cas objects where a particular attribute is equal to a given string or greater than a given value.

For this purpose, I have written the following generic method filterLibrarySingle to allow me to filter the Python list in the library class (self.Lib) based on various methods (filterMethod), attributes (filterField) and values (filterValue). Within the method I'm achieving this using list comprehensions.

On profiling my code, it would appear that this method can be quite a bit of a bottle neck! Does any one have an idea of how I could speed it up?

```
def filterLibrarySingle(self, filterField, filterMethod, filterValue1, filterValue2=None):
    if filterMethod == 'eq':
        self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib if getattr(cas, filterField) == filterValue1]

    elif filterMethod == 'lt':
        self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib if getattr(cas, filterField) < filterValue1]

    elif filterMethod == 'gt':
        self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib if getattr(cas, filterField) > filterValue1]

    elif filterMethod == 'le':
        self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib if getattr(cas, filterField) <= filterValue1]

    elif filterMethod == 'ge':
        self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib if getattr(cas, filterField) >= filterValue1]

    elif filterMethod == 'gelt':
        self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib if  getattr(cas, filterField) >= filterValue1 and getattr(cas, filterField) < filterValue2]

    elif filterMethod == 'gele':
        self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib if  getattr(cas, filterField) >= filterValue1 and getattr(cas, filterField) <= filterValue2]
```

I've wracked my brains for days on this to try and speed it up but I guess my Python knowledge simply isn't good enough!

I hope someone is able to help improve the performance of this method.

Many thanks

Mark

Comment: You might find a dict to be a nicer approach than all those elifs

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: I suspect that if this fn is a bottleneck for your program, the issue is not actually with how it's written but with how many times it's being called in your app.

Comment: You could be right there...it can be called quite a few times

Comment: Looking again, it is called quite a few times but still seems to be the bottleneck in terms of time/hit

Comment: While there are some straightforward constant-factor improvements that could be performed, it doesn't seem like there's much room for improvement within this method's requirements. Optimizations would have to happen through a higher-level restructuring; for example, the filtering could be deferred, and then when the filtered values are needed, the filters could be run through a query optimizer to merge filters on the same attribute and reorder filters to put higher-selectivity ones first.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to speed up this kind of processing is to eliminate the pure python steps in favor of high-speed C-based tools including `functools.partial()`, `itertools.imap()`, `itertools.ifilter()`, `operator.__eq__()`, and `hasattr()`.

Answer (score 0):

The operator library has all most of these functions defined, so could be rewritten more simply.

```
import operator
def filterLibrarySingle(self, filterField, filterMethod, filterValue1, filterValue2=None):
    self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib
                if operator.__dict__[filterMethod](getattr(cas, filterField),filterValue1)]
```

But it doesn't have `gelt` or `gele`.
So you may have to create a dictionary:

```
filter_methods = {
    'le': operator.le,
    ...
    'gelt': lambda a, b, c: a >= b and a < c
    'gele': lambda a, b, c: a >= b and a <= c
}

def filterLibrarySingle(self, filterField, filterMethod, filterValue1, filterValue2=None):
    if filterMethod in ['gelt', 'gele']:
        self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib
                    if filter_methods[filterMethod](getattr(cas, filterField), filterValue1, filtervalue2)]
    else:
        self.Lib = [cas for cas in self.Lib
                    if filter_methods[filterMethod](getattr(cas,  filterField), filterValue1)]
```

However, none of these will affect the performance of your application you will need to look at the logic you have.